# Prove that in any metric space $(X,\rho)$ closed disks are closed in the metric topology.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, solution-verification

Here is my attempt:

Let $(X,\rho)$ be a metric space. By definition, a subset of a metric space is said to be closed in the metric topology if its compliment is open in $(X, \rho)$. Suppose $D_r(a)=\{x\in X : \rho(a,x)\leq r\}$ is the set of closed disks with center $a$ and radius $r$. Let $y\in X\setminus D_r(a)$. Then $\epsilon=\rho(x,y)-r>0$. Next, if $x\in D_r(y,\epsilon)$ then by the triangle inequality $\rho(x,z)\geq \rho(x,y)-\rho(y,z)>\rho(x,y)-\epsilon=r$. Which shows $(D_r(a))^\complement$ is open.

I'm usually wrong and haven't been doing amazing in this class so if someone could help me out with this I would really appreciate it. We are using the text "Elementary Topology Problem Textbook" by O.Ya. Viro, O. A. Ivanov, N. Yu. Netsvetaev, and V. M. Kharlamov and are in chapter 1 section 4 titled metric spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First mistake: $y \in X \setminus D(a,r)$ implies $\rho (y,a )> r$.  Your definition of $\epsilon$ does not make sense because you did not say what $x$ is.

Second mistake: In the last part you did not say what $z$ is.

Correct proof: $\rho (y,a )> r$. Let $\epsilon =\rho (y,a )- r$. Let us show that $B(y,\epsilon) \subset  X \setminus D(a,r)$. Pick $z \in B(y,\epsilon)$. Then $\rho (z,y) <\epsilon= \rho (y,a )- r$. Hence,  $\rho(z,a) \geq \rho (y,a)-\rho (y,z) >\rho (y,a)-\epsilon=r$. This finishes the proof.

Comment: thank you for explaining this to me.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative: often it is shown that $d: X \times X \to \Bbb R$ is in fact a continuous function when $X$ is given the metric topology.
It follows that $d_a: X \to \Bbb R, x \to d(x,a)$ is also continuous for any fixed $a \in X$.

Then $D_r(a) = \{x\mid d(x,a) \le r\}= (d_a)^{-1}[(-\infty, a]]$ is closed as the inverse image of a closed set under $d_a$, using the order topology on $\Bbb R$.

Comment: that’s interesting. I would say that I probably shouldn’t go that route yet considering we haven’t discussed continuity in the class yet and I don’t fully understand that yet and don’t want to pretend to.

Comment: @sroma1997 True, in most texts this fact would come before continuity.